Problem inserting Material Output in SAP Business
When I try to insert a Material Output through postman to view and test data it asks me for the batch, but in the documentation there is no field to send the batch of the product or anything related.
{
    "DocDate": "2024-10-30",
    "Comments": "Salida de materiales para producción",
    "DocumentLines": [
        {
            "ItemCode": "1000041",
            "Quantity": 5,
            "WarehouseCode": "MP",
            "CostingCode": ""
        }
    ]
} 

este es el error:

endpoint: /b1s/v1/InventoryGenExits
